# Why is Flask not receiving my POST Blob?

Tags: javascript, flask, blob, form-data

My problem is that I'm sending a Blob to the server with FormData, but the server isn't getting it. Code looks like the following:

Flask server code:

```
@app.route('/save-record', methods=['POST'])
def save_record():
    app.logger.debug(request.form.keys()) #Shows only the title key, not the file key
```

Client JS Code:

```
var save = function() {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', record.blob, record.filename);
    form.append('title', searchedObj.title);
    //Chrome inspector shows that the post data includes a file and a title.                                                                                                                                           
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/save-record',
      data: form,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: No. Everything to do with the form I make above. Is enctype necessary?

Comment: The blob, btw, is a sound blob from recorder.js

Comment: are you sure? the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax?rq=1, suggests that that's not the way to go. And replacing the 'contentType:false' with 'contentType:multipart/form-data' didn't fix it. Do you mean something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check `request.files` for the file.

```
@app.route('/save-record', methods=['POST'])
def save_record():
    app.logger.debug(request.files['file'].filename)
```